# How to apply lock on particular column in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**How to apply lock on particular field so the same number is not generate again.**

- I have created algoritham in which it create string with using Year+000..+integer number
  example : "20150001","20150002","20150003" etc.
- The problem is that when the multiple user request for that number at that time the same number generated.

**Following function i call**

```
def get_algo_number(model_name,prefix) <br>
  year = get_year

  if model_name.count > 0 

    last_number = model_name.last.number

    if last_number[2..5].to_i > year.to_i
      return create_number(year,prefix)
    else
      # if letest generated number already exist then generate new number

        return last_number.next

    end
  else
    return create_number(year,prefix)
  end
end
```

Please help if you have any solution regarding apply lock.
Thanks

Comment: This will help you http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: thanks but this lock doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you wrap the lock in a transaction block. Btw this works with row level locking, you cannot lock just one column

Comment: can you provide the relevant code that generates the string?

Comment: If you're on postgresql, you should use sequences for this.

Comment: yes i m using postgresql db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, i resolved this problem by using multi-threading.**

Comment: I don't think multi-threading would resolve that. Can you be more specific?